# git reset to commit specify the branch

Tags: git

I want to create a script that automatically inspect given commits.
The command to inspect a specific commit is

```
git checkout -B dummy
git reset --hard e3f1e37
```

It will work fine.

But this is a script and if the first command fails for any reason, it will destroy the previous branch the code was on. How can I give the branch name to `git reset` to avoid such a problem? or limit the scope of the `git reset`?

Comment: try ```git checkout -B dummy && git reset --hard e3f1e37```, using ```&&```, if the first command failed (exit code not 0), then the second command will not be executed

Comment: to give a name to specific commit, you can use ```git tag``` https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to give a name to a commit before you can switch to it. You can use just

```
git checkout --detach e3f1e37 --
```

This puts you into the [detached head](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/#_detached_head) state, i.e., the currently checked-out commit is not on any branch.

Comment: fatal: git checkout: --detach does not take a path argument 'e3f1e37'

Comment: @mercury Pick a commit ID that exists. I've also appended `--` as disambiguation.